# How to find out SQL Server options updated

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Two days ago, we started having problems on a production server executing stored procedures.
No problems on any other servers, only production.
Our investigations found out that the server connection properties XACT ABORT were set to ON, and this option is ON only on the production server.
Now we want to understand when, and possibly who, changed this option. We are looking at the system tables but till now without any luck.
Is there someone who knows if there is a way?

Comment: Your question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032652/how-to-find-out-sql-server-options-updated/47034614#47034614

Answer (score 0):

View errorlog or default trace if is ON

```
sp_configure'default trace enabled'

DECLARE @trc_path VARCHAR(500)
SELECT @trc_path = CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),value) FROM fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT)
WHERE property=2

SELECT @trc_path
SELECT 
    TEXTData,
    HostName,
    ApplicationName,
    DatabaseName,
    LoginName,
    SPID,
    StartTime,
    EventSequence
FROM fn_trace_gettable(@trc_path,1) fn
WHERE TEXTData LIKE '%configure%'
```